# Builder-like pattern for extensible Hierarchy (weak ADT)

Tags: scala, generics, builder, implicit

### TL;DR

Given a hierarchy of case classes, a tree of instances can be constructed:

- How do I convert that into "something else" via appropriate builders in a type safe (and user friendly) manner (without touching or altering the respective case classes) ?

## Update 2021-02-25

I could make it *somehow* work with

```
import org.scalajs.dom.console

trait Root
case class Bob(name: String, as: Seq[Root]) extends Root
case class Charles(value: Int, as: Seq[Root]) extends Root


trait Builder[T] {
  // can not make T covariant, as this is obj is not in a covariant position
  def build(obj: T) : String
}

object Foo {
  var r: Map[Root, Builder[Root]] = Map()
  def attachBuilder[T <: Root](a: T, builder: Builder[T]) : Unit = {
    val e = (a, builder)
    r = r + e.asInstanceOf[(Root, Builder[Root])]
  }

  def b(name : String, as: Root*)(implicit builderB: Builder[Bob]): Bob = {
    val b = Bob(name, as)
    attachBuilder(b, builderB)
    b
  }

  def c(value: Int, as: Root*)(implicit builderC: Builder[Charles]): Charles = {
    val c = Charles(value, as)
    attachBuilder(c, builderC)
    c
  }

  def build(obj: Root) : String = {
    r(obj).build(obj)
  }
}

object UseMe {

  implicit val builderB: Builder[Bob] = new Builder[Bob] {
    override def build(obj: Bob): String = {
      obj.name.toString + obj.as.map(a => Foo.build(a)).mkString(" ")
    }
  }

  implicit val builderC: Builder[Charles] = new Builder[Charles] {
    override def build(obj: Charles): String = {
      obj.value.toString + obj.as.map(a => Foo.build(a)).mkString(" ")
    }
  }

  def yahoo() : Unit = {
    val x = Foo.b("martin", Foo.b("b2"), Foo.c(127))
    console.log("This is x: " + Foo.build(x))
  }
}
```

Still, I am very *unsatisfied*. Idea, I followed: Have a map that catches the respective builder for Bob or Charles. Still,

- `Builder[T]` can not be made covariant. This prevents Builder[Bob] to be a subtype of Builder[Root]
- I do not see the proper type signature for Map, so I had to typecast.

### Requirements

- Hierarchy of Root, Bob, Alice is extensible (so can not be sealed)
- No use of static typing (by means of Shapeless HList or similar) as I simply will not have the full types as I am doing computations to assemble the tree.

### Questions

- What is a better approach?

## Original Post

### Prelude

Sigh .... mind-bending waste of hours ....... I seriously need your help!

### Scenario

Given an ADT

```
trait A
case class B(name: String, as: Seq[A]) extends A
case class C(value: Int, as: Seq[A]) extends A
```

that is expected to be extended (not sealed).

Further, assume a

```
trait Builder[T] {
  def build(obj: T) : String
}
```

Furthermore, with the code below we have "the creator functions" that expect the appropriate builders to in scope.

```
object Foo {
  def b(name : String, as: A*)(implicit builderB: Builder[B]): B = {
    ???
    // How to link ADT instance B with builder for B in a type-safe manner?
    // How to trigger builder for `as`: Seq[A] ?
  }

  def c(value: Int, as: A*)(implicit builderC: Builder[C]): C = {
    ???
    // How to link ADT instance C with builder for C in a type-safe manner?
  }
}
```

With that I want to be able, after defining appropriate builders as implicit vals for `B` and `C` to do

```
object UseMe {
  implicit val builderB: Builder[B] = new Builder[B] {
    override def build(obj: B): String = {
      obj.toString
      // and build the as
    }
  }

  implicit val builderC: Builder[C] = new Builder[C] {
    override def build(obj: C): String = {
      obj.value.toString
      // and also build the as
    }
  }

  val x = Foo.b("martin", Foo.b("b2"), Foo.c(127))

  // Questions
  // How to create a string representation (that is what the builder is doing) for x
  // Something like:
  // build(x)
}
```

By intention, I removed all my misleading tries in code, also not to induce any bias.

### Tries

- A builder impl that uses dynamic type information (via `case b: B => ...`) is working, but as I expect the ADT to be extended, this is not an option.
- All my tries to model by generic types have failed. (Approaches with HList (Shapeless) might be feasible but are not considered, as I think this can be solved in plain Scala)

### Questions

- How to define methods in `Foo`?
- How to solve builder pattern / creational pattern best for ADTs?

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I really do not understand what are you trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: The questions is "how to link the builders with the ADT (A, B, C), so that I can call something like `build(x)`where x is the ADT Tree.

Comment: If there is no `sealed` then this is not considered ADT (otherwise you would slap that name on almost any type hierarchy). The openness of your interface kind-a requires you to use something like a visitor pattern where double dispatch is handled by 2 interfaces calling each other through virtual methods.

Comment: Alternatively if the type information is always present (you ALWAYS know the exact type at call site) then you can create type classes and implement builder by delegating all operations to these type classes - similar to what you did but you would need builder on _both_ input and output.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the problem is that you have a heterogeneous list of `A`s and you want to call `build` on each element of the sequence. - **typeclasses** alone can not solve this problem, you need to: make the trait sealed, use the **magnet** pattern instead _(but your code would change a little)_, move the `build` method inside the trait and solve this using traditional dynamic dispatch, use an `HList` from **Shapeless** instead of a `Seq` and then require the presence of the `Builder` typeclass for each element of the `HList` _(this requires all the data to be static)_.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok: Ok with "not an ADT". Double-dispatch is not an option as I do not want to modify the type hierarchy of Root, Bob, Charles.
What do you mean by "builder on both input and output"????

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: Problem is: I want to convert a heterogeneous tree of `A`s (`Root`) via builders into something else. (String here)
And no, neither magnet pattern (I know it) nor HList is helpful IMO.

Comment: Why do you say they are not helpful? You can define your transformation as a magnet. Or, you can use an HList to preserve the type information of each element in the sequence to invoke each builder.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez; No worries. Why not convince me with working code that it is working as you suggest? :D